# Table border lines showing over panels ASP NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I'm currently trying to figure out what the hell is happening, when I pop up a panel(date picker) when clicking a textbox, I get the table borders overlapping on the panel.

I'm pretty new to ASP NET / c# etc but from what I can see there is no 'show on top' or 'force top' option within the panel properties.

Thank you very much in advanced, pic of the issue and code for that section below as well.

EDIT: it also only seems to be the 'dates' that have the lines, as you can see Mon / tues and the month picker don't seem to be affected.

I've now set EVERY style to z-index: -1; other than the panel which is z-index 99999 but still not working :(

Issue still happening but using the following code now:
[image: border lines from table being shown over pop up panel calendar]
Head

`<style type="text/css">
           #txtresumedate_PopupControlExtender
   {
         z-index:99999; 
   }`
Also tried and forced the cssstyle onto the panel:
`<style type="text/css">
           .panel
   {
         z-index:99999; 
   }`

Body:

```
            `<tr>
            <td class="style9">
                Likely resumption date?</td>
            <td class="style12">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtresumedate" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                <ajax:PopupControlExtender ID="txtresumedate_PopupControlExtender" 
                    runat="server" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" 
                    PopupControlID="Panel1" Position="Bottom" TargetControlID="txtresumedate">
                </ajax:PopupControlExtender>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="400px"  
                    BorderStyle="Double" >
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
                                onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" Width="200px">
                            </asp:Calendar>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel> 
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>`
```

Comment: I've tried setting it to 9999 but still not working, but sure what is going on, can styles override each other? 

Tried:
#txtresumedate_PopupControlExtender
        {
            z-index: 999999;
            
        }        
and 
        .panel
        {
            z-index: 999999;
            
        } 
and set the css style to the panel and still not worky :(

Comment: Cant post the entire rendered HTML due to it being 90,000 + chars, what part of it do you need? I'll try and dump the data on another site and link it back here.

Comment: what happens if you give Panel1 a background colour of white

Comment: DING DING DING!!! WE HAVE A WINNER!!!!! WOOOOOOHOOO!!! @Pete  submit that as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should solve you problem:

```
#Panel1 {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -  **use [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)**

```
<style type="text/css" />
   #txtresumedate_PopupControlExtender
   {
         z-index:99999; // make sure this should be greater then table's z-index
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Does the style / class have to be on the Popupcontrolextender or the panel or even the calendar within the Panel?

Comment: you just paste the above code in your HTML page in `<head>` tag.

Comment: try to use - View Page Source and see the `ID` of that popup calender and define css class as like above.

Comment: Still not working, and cant paste the code here. I'll edit my question with the new code.